# Neo4j Fast way to match fuzzy text property

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, alias

I have a reasonable number of nodes (roughly 60,000)

```
(:Document {title:"A title"})
```

Given a title, I want to find the matching node, if it exists. The problem is that the title I'm given is not consistent. That is, sometimes the beginning of a new word is Capital, sometimes it is all lower case. Sometimes Key-Words are combined with Kebab case, sometimes they are written normally as key words.

To compensate for that I use apoc and the Levenshtein distance between the given title and every node and only accept a node as a match if it is below some threshold:

```
MATCH (a:Document)
WHERE apoc.text.distance(a.title, "A title") < 10
RETURN a
```

This *does not scale well*. Currently a single lookup takes about **700 ms** which is too slow, given that this will likely grow to somewhere around 150,000 nodes.

I was thinking of storing / caching the occurrence of alternative titles in an `alias:[...]` property of the node and build an index over all aliases, but I don't know if this is possible in Neo4j.

What is the fastest way to "fuzzy find" a title given a large database of nodes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Neo4j 3.5 (currently on beta03), there are FTS (Full-Text Search) capabilities.

EDIT : I have written a detailed blog post about FTS in Neo4j : https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/01/11/neo4j-full-text-search-deep-dive.html

You can query then your documents using the [Lucene Classic Query Parser Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description).

**Create the index :**

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('documents', ['Document'], ['title','text'])
```

**Import some documents :**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///docs.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Document) SET n = row
```

**Query documents with title containing "heavy toll"**

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('documents', 'title: "heavy toll"')
YIELD node, score
RETURN node.title, score

╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════╕
│"node.title"                                                          │"score"           │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│"Among Deaths in 2016, a Heavy Toll in Pop Music - The New York Times"│3.7325966358184814│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

**Query for same title with a typo :**

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('documents', 'title: \\"heavy~ tall~\\"')
YIELD node, score
RETURN node.title, score
```

Notice the escaping of the quotes => \" , the string passed to the underlying parser should contain the quotes in order to perform a phrase query instead of a boolean query.

Also the `tidle` next to the terms indicate to perform a fuzzy search using the Damarau-Levenshtein algo.

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════╕
│"node.title"                                                          │"score"              │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│"Among Deaths in 2016, a Heavy Toll in Pop Music - The New York Times"│0.868073046207428    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│"Prisons Run by C.E.O.s? Privatization Under Trump Could Carry a Heavy│0.4014900326728821   │
│ Price - The New York Times"                                          │                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│"‘All Talk,’ ‘No Action,’ Says Trump in Twitter Attack on Civil Rights│0.28181418776512146  │
│ Icon - The New York Times"                                           │                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│"Immigrants Head to Washington to Rally While Obama Is Still There - T│0.24634429812431335  │
│he New York Times"                                                    │                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
```