# Iterating over nested list comphrension Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on this query, where I have to find a path from a node to a given list of nodes and a given list of relationships.

The problem is that `WHERE type(rel) in foundRels` I want to iterate over this list and do a fuzzy string match and not an exact string match, but I am not able to iterate over 2 lists.

This is my Cypher query.

```
MATCH path=(`C1`: COMPETENCY { name: 'C1' })-[*]->(e2)
WITH ['TRAVEL_TO'] as foundRels, ['CHENNAI'] as foundNodes
WHERE ANY (rel in relationships(path) WHERE type(rel) in foundRels)
AND ANY (node in nodes(path) WHERE node.name in foundNodes) 
RETURN apoc.path.elements(path) as pathElements
```

Hope it gives some idea.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149046/neo4j-fast-way-to-match-fuzzy-text-property

Answer (score 1):

Use the function 'contains' and 'unwind'. Unwind will expand your list into rows and contains will search for a string in type(rel).  Add below script into your query.

```
UNWIND foundRels as fRel 
WITH foundNodes 
WHERE ANY (rel in relationships(path) WHERE type(rel) contains fRel)
```